# How to run script contained in a package from shell

Tags: r

Is there an elegant way to run a script contained in an installed package from the command line, with arguments.

So, I'm aware that we could do something like:

```
Rscript path/package/scritpts/script.R arg1 arg2 arg3
```

But I'd like something that's more elegant. Because `path/package` can be ridiculous sometimes.

Comment: The best I can think of would be a function that automates the use of `system.file` (e.g., `Rscript pkgfunc package script.R arg1 arg2 arg3`), which barely reduces the codegolf here. Is there a reason that your above cmdline is so heinous?

Comment: @r2evans could you show an example of how to you would do that at the command line (the specific invocation).

Comment: @chris same deal, could you show an example of a specific invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirk has provided a viable solution by way of his `littler` package:

```
Rscript $(R -e 'cat(system.file("scripts","file.R",package = "pkg"))') arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an answer, but a naïve example using `system.file` and such:

```
# Rscript --vanilla pkgscript.R packagname scriptname.R arg1 arg2 arg3
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

if (length(args) < 2L) {
  # print out "Usage:" stuff
  stop("Usage: ...")
} else {
  fnames <- list.files(path = system.file(package = args[1]), pattern = args[2],
                       recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
  lfn <- length(fnames)
  if (lfn == 0L) {
    stop("no script found for: ", sQuote(args[2]))
  } else if (lfn == 1L) {
    # do something with args[-(1:2)]
    source(fnames)
  } else {
    stop("multiple scripts found for: ", sQuote(args[2]))
  }
}
```